# Send Data From Servlet To another ServerSocket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, serversocket

In my java project I have a Server class(using ServerSocket) and a client class(using Socket). In addition I also implemented a servlet application which is running on Tomacat 8
The servlet acts as extra input source(in other words its another client).

I'd like to send the data which is filled up from the servlet web page to the Server Socket. I already got the data from the web form using `request.getParameterMap()` command

I use json in order to wrap the data before sending it between Client and Server. i'd like to do the same with the servlet but I cant find the right way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have client class so you just need to use it effectively.
Make your client code generic with a simple interface so that it can be called from anywhere. Servlets are java classes, they can call any other class to do some additional work. In your case, you can use data received in Servlet and pass it on to the client to send it to your server.

Make sure that client code should not block the servlet for too long to decrease its responsiveness. If it does then you can do the client logic in a separate thread so that your servlet can respond quickly.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but passing the data to the client means that the servlet depends on the client. but I'm trying to make the servlet as separated client which I may or may not run whenever i want.

Comment: @Tamir1989 There is no problem if a servlet is dependent on another class to do some business logic. Just need to make sure that client code should not block the servlet for too long. If it does then you can do the client logic in a separate thread so that your servlet can respond quickly.

Comment: I still dont get it. Maybe I miss something. How do you send the data from servlet to client(lets assume I implemented an interface with getData Method)

Comment: @Tamir1989 How do you call a method from a class of another class? Just like that , what is the big deal ?

Comment: calling a method from different class aint the question here.
What happens if the servlet is not in the same project, how would you connect it to another serverSocket ?

Comment: @Tamir1989 create a jar for your client code and add it in your webapp